# GlusterFS use Geo-replication or normal gluster?

Tags: replication, glusterfs

We have 4 offices with ipsec lan2lan over fibre net (20-100 mbit on eache office, except one office with 10 mbit fibre). Latency is below 20 ms (between to of the offices with fastest network we have 2 ms). All offices have lan2lan between each other.

iperf between offices is typical 50-80 mbit.

We will have 0,5 - 1 tb data with little daily changes.

Is it recomended to use Geo-replication, or normal gluster replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use normal gluster replication, this because geo-replication is useful over wan2wan network, while glusterfs is good working over lan2lan or locally.